# Best way to communicate with a 3rd system via xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I am looking for the best way to implement, let's say a middle tier.

In the company I working for, we have two systems written with different programming languages. Each one must communicate with a third system via xml (rest and soap).

The first thing that came in my mind was to create a web application which would accept the calls from our internal systems but I stopped this implementation as I faced some issues regards the soap serialization (How could I do this?).

Except this I thought of WCF but I don't know if it is an appropriate solution for my case.

So, I would like to know which is the best way to implement this.

I'll appreciate any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use WCF for the middle-tier since it provides you with everything you need.

- Serialization
- Interoperability with Other Web Services Platforms
- Interaction with Applications built on other technologies, such as J2EE application servers, that support standard Web services. These applications can be running on Windows machines or on machines running other operating systems.
- Security
- SOAP All Version and REST
- Bindings
- Protocols
- Discovery

Comment: With wcf I can both send and receive soap and rest?

Comment: Just by configuration and some minor changes you can use same code base and serve your content in different ways. Let say you want to serve a SOAP service you just create the address, binding and contract. Check this article out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9f4391e9-8b9f-4181-a081-860d42b992a9/

Comment: I'de like to do one more question. Let's say that I choose to implement what I've already mentioned with wcf. Does it give me the flexibility to add what ever attributes or elements the soap or the rest could have? For example, with the xmlSerialization I use [XmlAttribute] for attributes and [XmlElement] for elements.Lastly I serialize the object and I posted it to the server. Could I do the same with wcf? After a google search I found only the way to create a wcf to allow others to communicate with my app, not the vice versa.  Thanks again

Comment: Yes WCF provides you with a vast amount of different ways you can achieve it. Check this article http://blogs.infosupport.com/supporting-attributes-in-wcf-rest-datacontract/ pay close attention to [XmlSerializerFormat]